# Tree Table : links are not shown

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtreetable

I've created a custom Table structure by combining a JTree and JTable.

it looks like this:

[image]

addition of leafs can be done to any element.

But when I try to add a node to a row which has children already, the link in not shown and the newly added row is also not shown.

this is how it looks when a new row is added to "Package":

[image]

But this problem does not occurred when a node is appended to a leaf.

But there are no errors or exceptions thrown.

after a node is added i do the following:

```
fireTableDataChanged
fireTableStructureChanged
scrollPathToVisible
```

although these are called the problem remains.

can anyone please give a suggestion?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Also consider this [alternative](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `updateUI()` on the JTable or JTree. `updateUI()` will propagate, rendering the rest of the components beneath it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#updateUI()